# Parameter passing bug in Boost.Log

Tags: c++, logging, boost

I've been experimenting with Boost.Log for the first time and quickly ran into problems. The following simple code does not work correctly for me

```
#include <boost/log/common.hpp>
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <boost/log/sources/logger.hpp>

namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;

BOOST_LOG_INLINE_GLOBAL_LOGGER_DEFAULT(my_logger, src::logger)

static void init()
{
    logging::add_file_log("test.log");
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    init();
    BOOST_LOG(my_logger::get()) << "hello, world";
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the log is saved in a file called `00000.log` instead of the `test.log` requested. Investigating a little it seems the problem is that the `"test.log"` argument isn't being passed down to Boost.Log's internal classes and when this happens a default file pattern of `"%N.log"` is used which results in the `00000.log` file name that I see.

Boost.Log uses Boost.Parameter to implement named parameters so I tried the being explicit about the parameter I'm using

```
logging::add_file_log(logging::keywords::file_name = "test.log");
```

This fails in the same way. Interestingly however if I pass two parameters the code works correctly, e.g.

```
logging::add_file_log(logging::keywords::file_name = "test.log", 
    logging::keywords::auto_flush = true);
```

I've not been able to determine where the fault lies, it could be Boost.Log, Boost.Parameter, or a compiler bug. What I'm looking for is some explanation of the nature of the bug. I can work around this particular issue as shown above, but if there's something fundamentally wrong with parameter passing in Boost.Log that's pretty serious. If anyone has any experience with this bug or if they could try the above code on their platform I'd appreciate it.

I'm using Boost 1.74.0 and Visual Studio 2019 and C++17. I'm using static Boost libraries which are linked statically with the C++ runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right. It is a bug.

Reducing it all the way:

```
std::cerr << (kw::file_name  = "first.log")[kw::file_name | boost::filesystem::path()] << std::endl;
```

Prints "". A slightly more informative test-bed:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d13f22372a0c7c8b)**

```
#include <boost/log/utility/setup/file.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    namespace kw = boost::log::keywords;
    auto test = [](auto params) {
        std::cerr << "Non-defaulted: " << params[kw::file_name] << std::endl;
        std::cerr << "Defaulted:     " << params[kw::file_name | boost::filesystem::path()] << std::endl;
    };

    test((kw::file_name = "aaa"));
    test((kw::file_name = "bbb", kw::auto_flush = false));
    test((kw::auto_flush = false, kw::file_name = "ccc"));
}
```

Prints

```
Non-defaulted: aaa
Defaulted:     ""
Non-defaulted: bbb
Defaulted:     bbb
Non-defaulted: ccc
Defaulted:     ccc
```

Clearly, the `| filesystem::path()` syntax is throwing a wrench. And it only manifests in the single-argument case.

---

#### Cause/fix?

The correct flow goes into `arglist::operator[]:

```
    template <typename Default>
    inline BOOST_CONSTEXPR reference
        operator[](
            ::boost::parameter::aux::default_r_<key_type,Default> const& d
        ) const
    {
        return this->get_default(d, _holds_maybe());
    }
```

Into

```
        // Helpers that handle the case when TaggedArg is empty<T>.
        template <typename D>
        inline BOOST_CONSTEXPR reference
#if defined(BOOST_PARAMETER_CAN_USE_MP11)
            get_default(D const&, ::boost::mp11::mp_false) const
#else
            get_default(D const&, ::boost::mpl::false_) const
#endif
        {
            return this->arg.get_value();
        }
```

Into `tagged_arg::

```
    inline BOOST_CONSTEXPR reference get_value() const
    {
        return this->value;
    }
```

---

The malfunctioning case goes into

```
    template <typename KW, typename Default>
    inline BOOST_CONSTEXPR Default&&
        operator[](
            ::boost::parameter::aux::default_r_<KW,Default> const& x
        ) const
    {
        return ::std::forward<Default>(x.value);
    }
```

This is at once incorrect as KW == boost::log::v2_mt_posix::keywords::tag::file_name, so one would have expected this overload to have been taken:

```
    template <typename Default>
    inline BOOST_CONSTEXPR reference
        operator[](
            ::boost::parameter::aux::default_r_<key_type,Default> const&
        ) const
    {
        return this->get_value();
    }
```

But. That's only defined for `tagged_argument_rref`, looks like that was an oversight (the overloads for `default_<>` are both there, for comparison).

### Checking The Hypothesis

If the problem is specific for `default_r_<>` then it should be gone with a default value that is an lvalue:

```
auto args = (kw::file_name = "aaa");
path lvalue;
std::cerr << "default_r_<>: " << args[kw::file_name | path()] << "\n";
std::cerr << "default_<>: "   << args[kw::file_name | lvalue] << "\n";
```

Which indeed prints

```
default_r_<>: ""
default_<>: aaa
```

### Fix

It stands to reason that the overload for `default_r_<keyword_type, ...>` needs to be added for `tagged_argument`. Indeed this works (on my machine).

I was going to create a PR, so I opened [issue #104](https://github.com/boostorg/parameter/issues/104). But when forking is turns out that there is already a fix in develop:

```
tree fff523c8fe0a3de1c1378a2292840f217cc4d6d3
parent 0f548424a5f966fadfa7a21a759c835729cbc009
author Andrey Semashev <andrey.semashev@gmail.com> Sun Mar 15 18:13:07 2020 +0300
committer Andrey Semashev <andrey.semashev@gmail.com> Sun Mar 15 18:20:34 2020 +0300

Fix argument value selection with an rvalue default.

In C++11 mode, when named parameter pack was a single tagged argument,
parameter value was not extracted when an rvalue default value was
provided by the user (instead, the default value was returned). This
commit adds a missing overload for default_r_, which returns the parameter
value.

Fixes https://github.com/boostorg/parameter/issues/97.
```

So, yeah look like the fix is months old and the issue duplicates #97.

Comment: I will look into this a bit more - cooking takes precedence

Comment: @john found and fixed the cause only to find that this issue is pending merge in `develop`. Grrr. Hope the information still helps you

Comment: Left some more comments there. Looks like maintenance is a mess there: apparently there was a fix in develop, which did get merged, but apparently it all has been reverted, while they knew that #97 fix was in it. I'm flabberghasted what's going on there, so I [left notes](https://github.com/boostorg/parameter/issues/104#issuecomment-686755761) for the devs to [figure that out](https://github.com/boostorg/parameter/issues/97#issuecomment-686755267).

Comment: For inspiration, your specific example does work correctly when putting `develop` branch of Boost Parameter on your include path. It's header only after all: https://imgur.com/a/rKnPO9f

Comment: Thanks for your work on this. Good to know that it is being fixed.